# Two column layout - content one colulmn centered but the other column top aligned to the top of the centered content

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, responsive

I'm looking for a way to create this two column layout, the content on the right is centred horizontally and vertically but the content on the left is centred horizontally and vertically aligned with the top of the content in column twos as the length of the content in column two changes the content in column one always stays aligned to the top.

Please take a look at the image attached as this is easier to explain visually

This can't just be a padded box because as the content on the right grows the padding reduces to stay centered, and the main columns need to stay a min height

[Updated layout image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGUwJ.png)

Based on Кольо Пеев answer below I've modified my codepen

https://codepen.io/nitrokev/pen/RwMQZeJ

```
<div class="fifty-fifty-project-details-grid">
<article class="fifty-fifty-content left lightblue">
    <div class="entry-content" >
        <h3>Content 1</h3>
    </div>
</article>
<article class="fifty-fifty-content right" >
    <div class="entry-content" >
      <h3>Content 2</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In enim lorem, sollicitudin ut accumsan in, porta sed dui. Sed sagittis est risus, ac luctus odio porta at. Vivamus at nibh et mi euismod sagittis et sed justo. Nulla pretium pellentesque eros, vel aliquam elit egestas eu. Aliquam erat lorem, tristique sit amet est eu, elementum porta augue. Morbi consequat magna felis, placerat convallis nisl placerat a. Nullam porttitor suscipit metus a condimentum. Nunc eleifend ex sed tristique tempus.  Nunc elementum ligula nec pulvinar mattis. Aenean tincidunt, odio in congue iaculis, ipsum quam hendrerit velit, id commodo mauris ante rhoncus odio. Sed eget nibh vitae ipsum consectetur porta sit amet eget ante. Donec ultricies lacinia ultricies. Nullam id porttitor leo. Quisque sit amet nisl ultrices sapien aliquet gravida. Nam auctor mi ut orci dictum, sit amet tempor metus eleifend. Donec rhoncus et justo ac sollicitudin. </p>
    </div>
</article>
</div>

.fifty-fifty-project-details-grid {
display: flex;
flex-flow: row wrap;
overflow: hidden;
min-height:45rem;
}
.fifty-fifty-content {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
 align-items: center;
 flex: 0 0 auto;
 width: 50%;
 margin-left: 0;
 margin-right: 0;
 height: auto;
 padding:3rem;
 }
 .left{
   background-color:#52AACB;
 }
 .right{
   background-color:#52CB8F;
 }
```

I think if there was a way to calculate the current height of the content in column two and apply it to column one, that might work?

Comment: Please update your question with a [mre] of your code, we can't troubleshoot images.

Comment: Ok I've added a codepen of where I got with both columns centred, but this isn't how I want it

Comment: for such calculations you have to use JavaScript.. CSS is not a painkiller for every layout problem so add some onLoad function with element selectors and you can get and set the height

Answer (score -1):

Try running this code snippet. I am not fully aware of what you expect since there is no real content given anywhere from your side, but maybe with a few more lines of CSS you can achieve what you desire.

```css
.container {
  min-height: 400px;
  background-color: #52CB8F;
  display: grid;
}
.container__parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  align-self: center;
}
.container__child {
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: #555;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  
}
.container__child:first-child {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.container__child:last-child {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container__parent">
  <div class="container__child">
    test string
  </div>
  <div class="container__child">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Facilisis mauris sit amet massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis. Aliquet enim tortor at auctor. Facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis enim lobortis. Eget nulla facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis enim. Amet nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer. Id aliquet lectus proin nibh. Interdum consectetur libero id faucibus. Ornare lectus sit amet est placerat in egestas erat imperdiet. Felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel. Arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum ut. Amet luctus venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna. Lobortis elementum nibh tellus molestie. Nibh praesent tristique magna sit amet purus gravida. Odio facilisis mauris sit amet massa vitae. Vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam lacus suspendisse faucibus. Orci phasellus egestas tellus rutrum.
  </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the test string text isn't vertically aligned with each other in this

Comment: then please update your question, so anyone can understand it.. read your question at the top and note you want text centered horizontally or so to say on the X axis and only one vertically or so to say on the Y axis..

Comment: please take a look at the image I think that explains it better than I can with words

Comment: No, it does not. There is a difference if content is HTML element or plain text.. to get the desired result

Comment: I have also updated my answer.. if it is not what you are looking for it is because YOU HAVE NOT PROVIDED CONSISTENT INFORMATION ON WHAT YOU EXPECT

Comment: I'm sorry that you aren't understanding, I think the image is pretty clear, thanks for trying though

Comment: I updated my answer, so yor expectations are met.. Colors are added, so you can visually understand how it works, to have it as "you want it" simply remove borders and have all backgrounds use the same color. Try running the code snippet Expanded !

Comment: And if you want 2 columns to have different colors just add an absolute positioned div with the correct color

Comment: Thanks, thats helped a lot, I've applied the same technique to a flex box version and it works well